# How do I apply a stylesheet to an element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, string

I need to be able to change out the css applied to the `<body>` on the fly.  How, using javascript, could this be accomplished?

My css is stored as a string in a Javascript variable.  I am not working with css files. The css consists of around 50 classes, so it doesn't make sense to apply them one-by-one.  I know how this could be accomplished by changing the lowest class, but I'm just trying to see if it's possible to do using Javascript commands and variables.

Pseudo Code

```
var x = "#nav-bar-wrapper {
  background-color: #4a3e7d;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}...";

function changeCss() {
    var el = $('myelement');
    SomeJavaScriptFunction(el, x);
}
```

Comment: You could create a style element, put the contents of `x` into its `textContent` and then append that to the head element?

Comment: Forgive me, but what is a style element?  I googled, but 'style element' is not the best search pattern to find what you are referring to.

Comment: [The style element, by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) - this element can be made by using `document.createElement('style')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @evolutionbox pointed out, it looks like you want to add new styles to the page. If so, just add them as text content in a style element:

```js
const css = '#nav-bar-wrapper { ... }'
function changeCss() {
    const el = document.createElement('style')
    el.textContent = css
    document.head.appendChild(el)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way of doing it would be:

```
document.querySelector("yourElement").style.cssText += "Your super long string will go here and itll work"
```

Although, I dont think theres a way of giving different elements a uniqe style all in one line other than appending a style tag to the html. To use the method above, you'd have to separate `#nav-bar-wrapper` and `#header-nav`

Just keep in mind to use `` rather than "" to make the string go onto multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more JavaScript-y method than using hacky style tags.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = () => {
  [
    [ 'background', 'black' ],
    [ 'color', 'white' ]
  ].map(([ prop, val ]) => {
    button.style[prop] = val;
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Hello there</button>
```

You could also try out https://cssinjs.org, which also works great in React.

Perhaps using jQuery's `.css()` function is worthy too: https://api.jquery.com/css/. It can take an object of CSS properties and apply them to an element.

```js
$('#button').on('click', () => {
  $('#button').css({ background: 'black', color: 'white' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Hi there</button>
```

You could also create a new style tag and append it to the body as many people have said. You can even append an external `link rel="stylesheet"` tag to the header to dynamically add a stylesheet from another URL! An alternative to this would be using the fetch API/jQuery AJAX/xmlhttprequest plus the code below:

```js
$('#button').on('click', () => {
  $('body').append('<style>#button { background: black; color: white; }</style>');
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button id="button">Hi there</button>
</body>
```

Another approach is using classes that you can dynamically add in JavaScript.

```js
$('button').on('click', () => $('#button').addClass('clicked'));
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Hi there</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a reference of your html element and after manipulate the DOM, here is an example:

```
document.getElementById('yourElementIdHere').style.color = 'red';
```

If you want to get your body reference to manipulate the DOM, you can do it. After this, you can change the style of your body using the style property, and use your string with your css.

```
document.querySelector("body").style = yourCssStringVar;
```

This link can help you, too:
[JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: Wouldn't I have to set each element? Is there a way to just blanket the page with a new set of rules?

Comment: You can get your body reference and add/remove your css classes, like this: document.getElementById(yourMainElementId).classList.add("my-class");